# How to configure incoming email in SharePoint Foundations without local SMTP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, configuration, incoming-email, smtp

How I can to configure incoming email in SharePoint Foundations without local SMTP?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the information is good, but i just checked the links and they are dead. Let me know if the basic info is enough to get you started.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/0d263b37-f002-4d9b-a7a1-2026f032f1f7/

The second answer by Jasonzh2010 has the best information...

> You don't have to run SMTP on Front-End Web Server but you have to run it somewhere to get the email in the "drop" folder as eml file and
>   configure your SharePoint (the timer service) to be aware the location
>   of the drop folder and pick up the eml files from there.
>
> The easiest way is to run SMTP server on Front-End Web Server and
>   select "automatic" as shown here
>   http://ethan-deng.tech.officelive.com/images/SPConfigureIncomingEmail.jpg
>
> The not so easy way is to run SMTP server somewhere else and share the
>   "drop" folder as network shared folder and give permissions to your
>   SharePoint Timer Service account. And in the settings as shown
>   http://ethan-deng.tech.officelive.com/images/SPConfigureIncomingEmail.jpg,
>   select "Advanced" and then give the network shared folder as
>   \myserver1\drop\
>
> You can read more here
>   http://anurasoftware.com/SPIncomingEmailSettings.aspx

Comment: I knew this above post but I still don't know how I can do it. Can you tell me step by step ho wI can do it? Thanks for your support,

Comment: Well, i can give you this http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/, which is the link i use to configure incoming email in general... you should just be able to follow the instructions for whatever is the SMTP server and share the drop folder and use an appropriate address where applicable. I have not personally done this as I normally just install SMTP locally, let me know how it goes/if you have further questions.

Comment: OK, so I should create only drop foledr and add full permissions to user. But where should I create this folder and who user should I add this permission? Thanks for your help,

Comment: The account the IIS application runs under i believe (either that or whatever the time service runs under, which should be the same if you didnt change it yourself), and where you put the drop folder doesnt really matter, the default on the SMTP server is fine, just share it out and make sure you know what address to use to access it ('\\<server name>\Drop' or something like that).

Comment: So I should create this folder on for example: \\<my server>\drop? I ask because in Central Administration in Configure Incoming E-mail Settings E-mail Drop Folder is given as exapmle "c:\inetpub\mailroot\drop"?

Comment: The example assumes you have an SMTP dropping onto the local drive, hence the 'C:\'. While it is not impossible to set it up as such using a script to transfer files from the SMTP server or setting the SMTP server to drop to a share which happens to be that file location, if your SMTP drops to its OWN C:\inetpub\mailroot\drop then your sharepoint server needs to pull from THAT folder, which would be \\<SMTP server>\Drop, or however you named it.

Comment: I did it but email still doesn't work... what should I do more? Once more thanks for support

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point you would need to either call Microsoft support,  or have someone help you in person. It is incredibly difficult to debug an issue like this without a whole lot more information and/or access to the given servers.

Comment: OK, so I will look answer in internet. But I just wonder to which user I should give permission to drop folder?

Comment: WSS_ADMIN_WPG (or the members of the group) should have NTFS Modify rights, WSS_WPG should have Read & Execute rights.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question here: [How to Enable Email in Lists Without Using Exchange?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39458/how-to-enable-email-in-lists-without-using-exchange/39497#39497) where the fellow tells how to configure incoming mail - in my case, using an external email server.

[SharepointGeorge](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/) showed me how to configure iis6 for use with the SMTP server.  iis6 comes on your Windows Server 2008, and it is only really used for email.  Using it won't mess up your iis7.

To enable mail in your sharepoint lists, you need to configure it in Central Administration - in "System Settings/Configure Incoming Email".

[update]
Ah, look at this [other thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44136/how-does-internal-email-get-to-the-smtp-client-of-a-sharepoint-server/51254#51254) where I answer in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use smtp4dev - easy to use small SMTP Server.
http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Install the smtp4dev server to any server you want, configure ports. Then open CA and configure outcome email server.