# How to add required column comments in library Sharepoint Fundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, word, library

I try to add required column "comments" in library but I have problem, when I add column and I check in "Require that this column contains information:" when I try to save this file (.doc) I don't see window to enter comments?

I need that each user must add comments before close file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a custom Content Type using the Document Content type, and setting a document library to use this content type. Have you tried it? Are you sure if "Allow management of content types" option is also turned on?

The mandatory fields you add to the custom content type, will show in the Document Information Panel in Microsoft Word, and will force user to enter some data before closing the file.

Comment: Allow management of contentypes is very important!

Comment: Yes I have turn on "Allow management of content types" I did in Document library settings I found Document Content Type enter there and I changed column Comments Status from "Optional" to "Required" but nothing is change...

Comment: Is it a list or a site level column?

Comment: I'm not sure, how I can check it?

Comment: Go to Site Settings -> and Site Columns and see if Comment column is existing there. Have your tried re-creating the column as a mandatory, and adding it again to the Document Content Type?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I checked that and my column comments is in Document columns category but I didn't try to re-confingure for now... So I do it and let you know... Once more thakns for your support

Comment: I did it and now is good and my problem was resolved :) Thanks and best regards

Comment: Great to know :). Mark it as an answer my post has helped you ;)

Comment: I have once more question but that is from another topic, I created post about incoming email, maybe you will have some ideas? If you have time? thanks :) this is link...  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38346/how-to-configure-incoming-email-in-sharepoint-foundations-without-local-smtp

Comment: Andrzej if you find @Falak-mahmood 's answer to be helpful, please mark as answer to encourage any further assistance. Falak: there is no guidance for this, we can only encourage users to mark as answer to reward helpful answers

Comment: Andrzej, I would do if I have time. @AndersRask Thank you for your concern.

Comment: with pleasure, but where can I do it? :)

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Read more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work